# Xubuntu 14.04 - Strange "Log Out" button behavior

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, login, shutdown, lightdm

I'm currently using Xubuntu 14.04.

Today, February 19th, I got home and was presented with some upgrades (which updated Xubuntu to the 14.04.4 point release). But I don't know if these upgrades are related to my problem:

When I open the Whisker menu and click the "Log out" button, instead of the usual Log out/Restart/Shutdown options, it goes straight to the LightDM login screen. So to fully shutdown my computer I have to either do it from the login screen or run `sudo shutdown -h now` from a terminal.

Is it a known bug? Maybe related to the 14.04.4 update? How can I get my Log Out options back?

Thanks in advance,

Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I unchecked "Ask before logging out" (or something like that) in the Startup applications. I checked the box again and eureka! It came to life again.

Thanks for all the answers anyway.

Comment: Ah yes, Prompt on Logout.  That makes sense.  Glad you got it fixed.  =)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the settings to your Whisker Menu by clicking on your Whisker Menu, then go to `Settings`, then `Panel`.

Click on the Items Tab, then on the Whisker Menu

[image]

Click the gear to the right.

Then click on the Behavior Tab, and make sure the appropriate boxes are checked and configured correctly

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy! I'm not on my computer now but I'll give you a answer tomorrow. I thought that was strange behavior because I didn't change any Whisker settings. After the upgrade it simply happened. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @EduardoCola No problem!  I hope it didn't change your Whisker settings, but it would be a great place to start.  I have grown to love Xubuntu!  It is my favorite DE now.  =)

Comment: Mine too. After like 10 different DEs that couldn't satisfact me (LXDE - too simple, KDE - too bloated, Unity - too slow, etc. etc.) I found Xfce and fell in love with it! Nice to see someone's with me.

Comment: @EduardoCola I couldn't agree more.  Xfce has really impressed me because it looks good, fast, and low memory usage.  My applications launch quickly and seem very stable as well.  Best move I ever made!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other places to access the log out, shut down, etc. menu if ever needed.

1. Run `xfce4-session-logout` from terminal. I have a keyboard shortcut for this that I use.
2. It is available from the context menu by right clicking on the Desktop then Applications > Log Out.
3. It is an option among the Whisker Menu items (not just on the top right).
4. It is an option when you run `xfce4-appfinder` or Application Finder and search for Log Out.